# Redirecting the website domain call to Codeigniter folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, server, continuous-integration, hosting

I have a domain with a subdirectory called **main**, which includes the Codeigniter files and `index.php`.

How can i redirect to Codigniter/index.php from `default.php`, which is included in my `public_html` folder?

Thank you all

[this image for detail my case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yt67I.jpg)

Comment: The answer depends on the type of web server your running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this code in your default.php file

```
<?php 
header('Location: /main/index.php'); 
?>
```